# How do I add external property file location to Spring Boot application deployed to tomcat 6?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, tomcat6

I have a Spring Boot application that I configure with annotations. I have application.properties and application-{profile}.properties files already with data in them. Problem is I now want to define a WAR-external location on the Tomcat 6 server where I can put configuration files *that take precedence*. That is, any settings I put in those properties files should trump any values in application.properties or application-{profile}.properties.

How can I accomplish this in the easiest possible way?

I have already tried to add @PropertySources but that has a lower priority in the properties files order so that is not a possible solution. Can I change the property file loading order easily?

It is not possible to add environment variables to the server, since that might affect other deployed applications. The WAR must be self-contained and deliver everything it needs (except this external properties override file).

Comment: So you are deploying your app on a Tomcat 6 server? Why do you use Spring-Boot then?

Comment: Because it's 2016? :) Most likely the tomcat server will be upgraded in the near future. But I need a solution now.

Comment: Just using Spring Boot because it's 2016 is no reason. Spring Boot basically is for wiring up a complete environment with integrated server, so why do you use an extra tomcat 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure `spring.config.location` [as described in the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) or you could implement an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` if you want this to apply regardless.

There is a sample in this [university session at Devoxx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uof5h-j0IeE) where [we showcase how to read a file from the home directory](https://youtu.be/uof5h-j0IeE?t=1h17m46s) and add it after command line properties. You could do pretty much the same thing and order them the way you want.

The sample app is [available here](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/hello-service-auto-configuration) if you want to give that a try.

Comment: spring.config.location can only be changed with an environment variable (not usable as I explain above) or input parameter, which I don't think applies to Tomcat (I might be wrong).

Comment: But postProcessEnvironment sounds promising. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Looking at the sample, it was easy enough to insert my own property file, if present. Thanks!